# Duda al enviar información al modal (Edición de registros)

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, modal

sigo con el back de una empresa y ahora me encuentro con un problema que no se como solventarlo.
Estoy haciendo todas las ediciones de los registros de la BD, con modales y con AJAX. Gracias a esta página algunos compañeros me han ayudado a realizarlo. Bien ahora explico el problema.

Tengo una página que se llama `ver-cliente.php`, en la cual muestro las graficas de sus pedidos anualmente, además en datatables muestro todos los pedidos que a realizado este cliente. Bien cada fila de cliente tiene un icono de editar el el pedido para que administración pueda hacer lo siguiente. Cuando le dan al editar les sale un Modal con algunos datos del pedido, como el producto, el precio, fecha y alguno más.

Vale, dentro de ese modal cargo los datos de una BD en un select, que sale del stock de las maquinas. Ese stock se conecta con la tabla de `productos`. Se conectan de este modo:  Tabla Referencias: idProducto - Tabla Productos: id.

Vale lo que necesito es que en el pedido esta el producto que a pedido, necesito que en ese Select solo salgan las referencias que pertenecen a esa maquina y que esten con estado 0.

`tabla pedidos`

```
  <tbody>
    <?php
     //var_dump($_GET);
     $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT((pedidos.Fecha),'%d/%m/%Y') Fecha, pedidos.id AS pedID, pedidos.Numero, DATE_FORMAT((pedidos.Vencimiento),'%d/%m/%Y') Vencimiento, pedidos.Producto, pedidos.Tipo, FORMAT(pedidos.Total, 2) Total, pedidos.Estado, productos.id, productos.producto, productos.alias FROM pedidos, productos WHERE pedidos.Producto = productos.id AND Iduser = " .$_GET['ID']);
    mysqli_set_charset("utf8");
    while($res = $results->fetch_array()) {
    ?>
    <tr class="dato_tabla tabza">
       <td class="tdfgaz" id="Idp<?php echo $res['pedID']; ?>" style="display: none;"><?php echo $res['pedID']; ?></td>
       <td class="tdfgaz" id="Fecha25<?php echo $res['pedID']; ?>"><?php echo $res['Fecha']; ?></td>
       <td class="otrotdfgaz" id="Numero<?php echo $res['pedID']; ?>"><?php echo $res['Numero']; ?></td>
       <td class="otrotdfgaz" id="Vencimiento<?php echo $res['pedID']; ?>"><?php echo $res['Vencimiento']; ?></td>
       <td class="otrotdfgaz" id="Producto<?php echo $res['pedID']; ?>"><?php echo $res['producto']; ?> <?php echo $res['alias']; ?></td>
       <td class="otrotdfgaz" id="select2-4<?php echo $res['pedID']; ?>"><?php
          if ($res['Tipo'] == 1) echo "<span class=\"exp-label\">Alquiler</span>";
          if ($res['Tipo'] == 2) echo "<span class=\"exp-label\">Comprada</span>";
          if ($res['Tipo'] == 3) echo "<span class=\"exp-label\">Exp.Compartida</span>";
          if ($res['Tipo'] == 5) echo "<span class=\"exp-label\">Alq. Opción a compra</span>";
      ?>
     </td>

   <td class="otrotdfgaz" id="Total<?php echo $res['pedID']; ?>"><?php echo $res['Total']; ?>€</td>
   <td class="otrotdfgaz" id="select2-1<?php echo $res['pedID']; ?>">
       <?php
          if ($res['Estado'] == 1) echo "<span class=\"conect-label\">Pagado</span>";
          else echo "<span class=\"desconect-label\">Vencido</span>";
      ?>
   </td>


   <td class="otrotdfgaz" id="select2-3<?php echo $res['pedID']; ?>">
       <?php
         if($res['Referencia'] == 0) echo "<span>Sin asignar</span>";
           else{
       ?>
         <span><?php echo $res['Referencia']; ?></span>
       <?php  } ?>

   </td>

   <td class="tdfgaz right">
      <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; margin-right: 5px; font-size: 14px;">
      <i class="icon-doc " aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
      <button type="button" class="pedido" value="<?php echo $res['pedID']; ?>"><i class="icon-note" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>


      </td>
     </tr>
     <?php } ?>
   </tbody>
```

`Con esto recibo los datos en el modal`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.pedido', function(){
     var id=$(this).val();
     var Idp=$('#Idp'+id).text();
     var Estado=$('#select2-1'+id).children('span').first().text();
     var Numero=$('#Numero'+id).text();
     var Producto=$('#Producto'+id).text();
     var Total=$('#Total'+id).text();
     var Tipo=$('#select2-4'+id).children('span').first().text();
     var Ref=$('#select2-3'+id).children('span').first().text();


     var fecha=$('#Fecha25'+id).text();
     var res = fecha.split("/");
     var fechaFormateada = res[2] + "-" + res[1] + "-" + res[0];
       document.getElementById('eFecha').value = fechaFormateada;

     var fecha=$('#Vencimiento'+id).text();
     var res = fecha.split("/");
     var fechaFormateada = res[2] + "-" + res[1] + "-" + res[0];
        document.getElementById('eVencimiento').value = fechaFormateada;


     $('#pedido').modal('show');
     $('#eIdp').val(Idp);
     $('#eNumero').val(Numero);
     $('#eProducto').val(Producto);
     $('#eTotal').val(Total);


     //alert(Estado);
        if(Estado == 'Pagado')
        $('select#select2-1').val('1').trigger('change');
           else
        $('select#select2-1').val('0').trigger('change');
           if(Tipo == 'Alquiler')
        $('select#select2-4').val('1').trigger('change');
           if(Tipo == 'Comprada')
        $('select#select2-4').val('2').trigger('change');
           if(Tipo == 'Exp.Compartida')
        $('select#select2-4').val('3').trigger('change');
           if(Tipo == 'Alq. Opción a compra')
        $('select#select2-4').val('5').trigger('change');

           if(Ref == 'Sin asignar')
        $('select#select2-3').val('0').trigger('change');
           else
        $('select#select2-3').val('').trigger('change');
            });
         });
    </script>
```

`Aquí os pongo un ejemplo de como imprimo los datos en el modal`

```
<div class="col-lg-5 padleft">
  <div class="form-group marcerooo">
     <label>Total</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control inputmiocont corpiii" id="eTotal" name="eTotal">
  </div>
</div>
```

`Y aquí el select donde tiene que sacar las refencias`

```
<select id="select2-3" value="" class="form-control" name="select2-3">
  <option value="0">Sin asignar</option>
  <?php
  //$row = $('#select2-3' + row_id);
  //var_dump($_GET);
  $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM referencias WHERE estadoMaquina = 0 ");
  mysqli_set_charset("utf8");

  while($res = $results->fetch_array()) {
  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $res['id']; ?>"><?php echo $res['referencia']; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Creo que no me dejo nada, siento la parrafada pero quiero exlicarlo lo mejor posible. ;)

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Qué problema te da?

Comment: Hola @Javi Mollá de nuevo, pues ahora el select me saca todas las referencias que estén en estado 0, no se como coger el valor del pedido para que solo me muestre las disponibles de la maquina comprada

Comment: Supongo que quieres filtrar las opciones que muestra el select por producto ¿Es así? ¿En la tabla de referencias tienes el valor del producto por el cuál quieres filtrar?

Comment: Exacto eso es lo que quiero, si en referencia hace conexion con los productos a través de idProducto

Comment: Añade un identificador a cada option con el idProducto y el idReferencia, de modo que puedas luego recorrerlos con javascript y ocultarlos según el idProducto seleccionado

Comment: Pero para eso hay que modificar la primera consulta para que también saque de referencias entiendo?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83000/discussion-between-javi-molla-and-miguel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder ocultar las opciones que no corresponden según el identificador de producto tienes que marcarlas con un identificador para poder ocultarlas mediante javascript:

```
<option value="<?php echo $res['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $res['id'].'_'.;$res['idproducto'] ?>"><?php echo $res['referencia']; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
```

Como estás usando la librería select2, en el javascript que se encarga de abrir el modal, marcar como deshabilitadas esas opciones:

```
$('select#select2-3 option').each(function(index, option) { 
  var ids = option.id.split('_');
  if (ids.length == 2) {
    var optionQuery = $(option);

    if (ids[1] == idProducto) {
      optionQuery.prop('disabled', false); 
    } else { 
      optionQuery.prop('disabled', true); 
    }
  }
});
```

Y luego poner en el css los elementos deshabilitados de ese control como no visibles:

```
.select2-result .select2-disabled {
    display: none;
}
```